# Why is adding DatePipe to an Injectable Service constructor failing?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

***NullInjectorError: No provider for DatePipe!***

I get that error when I tried to add the DatePipe to a service constructor.

Note: **DatePipe is already specified in the list of providers.**

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
...

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
    ...
    ...
    constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}
```

Comment: Did you add your pipe to the relevant module's providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Date pipe is a Pipe, so you not inject, only use it

The "old way" to use in .ts is create an instance and use transform,e.g.

```
const datepipe=new DatePipe('en-US')
const date=new Date()
console.log(datepipe.transform(date,'long'))
```

From Angular 6 (some time ago) you can use directly the function [formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate)

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common'

const date=new Date()
console.log(formatDate(date,'long','en-US')
```

In you want you can inject in constructor the LOCALE to use this LOCALE as argument

```
constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {}
const date=new Date()
console.log(formatDate(date,'long',this.locale)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add DatePipe in app.module provider

```
providers: [DatePipe],
```